# I need to iterate over an array and add elements in certain conditions

Tags: arrays, ruby

Hello i need to iterate over an array in ruby and add elements during this iterations.But i have a problem: let's say that the length of the array is 6 , if i add one more element and it is not the end of the iteration it won't go through all the array because the length is increased by 1 each time the condition is executed ex:placing a -1 between all the 2 of this array.

```
vet = [1,2,2,2,2,2]
for i in 0...vet.length do
 if vet[i]==2
   i+=1 #this is because the insert method always replace the element in i 
   vet.insert(i,-1)
   print "#{vet} \n" # [1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, 2] there is still a pair without a -1 
                                                                   # between them 
 end
end
```

how to solve this properly?

Comment: Write the expected output

Comment: [1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2,-1, 2]

Comment: What if the input is `[1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]` or `[1, 2, 2, 2, 1]`?

Comment: The problem still happens in the first array you said , but not in the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, there is *never* a need to use loops in Ruby. You should always prefer to use higher-level iteration constructs. Also, *never* mutate a data structure while you are iterating over it. (Of course, if you know me, you know I am a fan of functional programming, and thus I would say, never mutate a data structure *at all*.)

Here's a couple of ideas how I would solve the problem:

```ruby
indices = vet.
  each_cons(2).
  with_index.
  map {|pair, index| if pair == [2, 2] then index end }.
  compact

indices.reverse_each {|index| vet.insert(index + 1, -1) }
```

This actually mutates `vet` and does so while iterating over it, which are both things I said above not to do. However, it does so in a safe manner, by extending the array *from the back* so that the indices yet to be processed don't shift around.

It also uses the rather "low-level" `Enumerable#reverse_each` iterator, which is actually not much better than a loop.

Here is a version that does not mutate `vet` and uses higher-level iterators:

```ruby
([nil] + vet).
  each_cons(2).
  flat_map {|a, b| if [a, b] == [2, 2] then [-1, b] else b end }
```

Note that even without the bug, the code in your question is still wrong: you say you want to place a `-1` between all the `2`s of the array. However, your code places a `-1` after every `2`.

So, for example, if the input is `[2]`, your code will produce `[2, -1]` instead of the correct result, which is `[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the array between adjacent `2`'s via [`slice_when`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html#slice_when-method) and then re-combine the chunks by putting `-1` in-between them via [`inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html#inject-method):

```
vet = [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

vet.slice_when { |i, j| i == 2 && j == 2 } #=> [[1, 2], [2], [2], [2], [2]]
   .inject     { |a, b| a + [-1] + b }     #=> [1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2]
```

Note that `slice_when` operates on adjacent numbers in `vet`, whereas `inject` operates on adjacent chunks, i.e. sub-arrays. (more precisely, `a` is the first chunk initially and the block's previous result on subsequent calls)

The `+` operation is [`Array#+`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#2B-method). It looks very clean and symmetric, but unfortunately it creates several temporary arrays. It would probably be more efficient to use `push` and `concat` instead:

```
.inject { |a, b| a.push(-1).concat(b) }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do that as follows.

```
arr = [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

The following returns a new array and does not mutate `arr`:

```
arr.each_with_object([]) do |n, a|
  a << -1 if n == 2
  a << n
end
  #=> [1, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2]
```

If you wish to modify `arr` in place:

```
arr.replace(arr.each_with_object([]) do |n, a|
  a << -1 if n == 2
  a << n
end)
  #=> [1, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2]
```

```
arr
  #=> [1, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2]
```

See [Array#replace](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-replace).